# Ошибка в javascript

Tags: php, sql, javascript

Теперь работает ок, но идет другая кодировка, до фига таких ошибок. Как исправить?

> `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> http://localhost/u/images/avatars/
> %EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD.%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD.jpgFailed`

Если у меня

```
function load() {
    document.getElementById('button_my').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('my').innerHTML = '' + '';
    document.getElementById('choise_area').setAttribute("class", "choise_area1");
    return false;
}
```

и в кавычках много текста, то как мне использовать функцию iconv?

Comment: Добавьте `header('Content-type:text/javascript;charset=utf-8');` .

Comment: ну нет такой картинки на сервере. попробуй просто в браузере 
    http://localhost/u/images/avatars/%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD.%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD.jpg

если картинка будет то в js запросе косяк типа пробела точечки или еще чего

Comment: оно далжно быть
images/avatars/Максим.макс.jpg

Comment: а он переводит в %EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD.%EF%BF%
вот так он открывает
http://localhost/u/images/avatars/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC.%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ICONV](http://www.php.su/functions/?iconv):

```
iconv("in charset", "out charset", $string)
```

о майн гад

```
$foto=iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251", $name_photo);
$url="http://localhost/u/images/avatars/".$foto.".jpg";
```

и будет у тебя вместо

```
%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD.%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD
```

вот это

```
Максим.макс
```

Но не советую сохранять на серваке кирилические файлы, ghot переименовывать в транслит, меньше потом косяков выползет + к одному регистру их ровняй, чтобы еще меньше косяков было, косяки вылезут если сервак на *nix системе.

Comment: майн гад? :DDD

Answer (score 0):

А еще лучше отказаться от кодировки windows-1251 и перетопать на нормальную UTF-8.

1. UTF-8 позволяет работать одновременно с несколькими языками, т.е. выдавать тексты, в которых используются символы разных алфавитов и даже иероглифы. С использованием кодировки 1251 это невозможно;
2. использование UTF-8 позволяет отказаться от кодовых таблиц, трансляций символов и всех прочих извращений, что были ранее с однобайтовыми кодировками;
   Нет кучи кодировок для одного и того же языка, как это было ранее для русского: cp1251, cp866, koi8r, iso8859-5